# class number of biquadratic fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Can any one provide some references which treat the relation between the class number of a biquadratic field and the class numbers of its sub-fields using the analytic class number formula ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See section VIII.7 (Brauer relations) in Fröhlich-Taylor: Algebraic number theory, especially Theorem 74 there.