# Is there any relation between $h_{d_1},h_{d_2}$ and $h_{d_1d_2}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

$h_{d_1}, h_{d_2}$  and $h_{d_1d_2}$ are  class number of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d_1}),\Bbb Q(\sqrt{d_2}),\ and \ \Bbb Q(\sqrt{d_1d_2})$  respectively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a relation between the class numbers of those quadratic fields *and* the class number of the biquadratic field $\mathbf Q(\sqrt{d_1},\sqrt{d_2})$. The key term to look for is "Brauer relation", which has a wider scope than just this example. A reference for this topic has already been mentioned in an earlier MO question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262735/class-number-of-biquadratic-fields?rq=1).  See also equations (2.1) and (2.2) of Bosma and de Smit's "Class number relations from a computational point of view" (J. Symbolic Computation ${\mathbf{31}}$ (2001), 97-112).